# What's the word for "writing in braille"?

Tags: word-request

What's the word for "writing in braille"? Since braille is not written per se since we don't use a pen to "write in braille"? What's the verb we use to mean "writing in braille"?

For example:

> Robert finished ___ braille and gave the book for his blind friend to
>   read.

Comment: It certainly is possible to write by hand in Braille. There is a kit with a frame and  stylus available, such as [this one](https://www.hamara-bandhan.org/en_Braillekits.html). The stylus is used to make tactile impressions, as opposed to a visible impression such as on wax.

Comment: "{[Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille)} is traditionally written with embossed paper." - You write in braille by [*embossing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_embossing). That's the word for it, but that's not what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use *to write* even if no pen(cil) is involved. We still say that an author "writes a book" even though most manuscripts are digital these days. So

> Robert finished writing braille and gave the book for his blind friend to read.

is perfectly normal even if Robert is using a braille printer to produce the book.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd say "writing Braille" or "writing _in_ Braille" in that sentence. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writing+Braille%2Cwriting+in+Braille%2Cwriting+braille%2Cwriting+in+braille&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows both are in use.